# Simple bug on Apache 2.4 or CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4

I am dealing for days with this problem and it happens that I got to the conclusion it has to be a bug... unfortunatelly. I hope that with your expertise I can know for sure if it's a bug on Apache, CentOS 7 or something else.

I have a fresh minimal CentOS 7 installation with LAMP. Apache is at its latest version 2.4 with prefork as MPM. The server where I can reproduce the "bug" has 2 GB of RAM with a 256 MB swap partitions and runs with 2 vCPU. The bug does not happen with CentOS 6 so I think this bug has some mix of CentOS + Apache, have no idea which one is guilty.

This is the problem: when I start my Apache everything works fine, after a few seconds the `httpd` processes start using swap memory for no reason - I will tell you later how I know that. My first thought is that I am running low on RAM. So I execute `free` and to my surprise this is what I see:

[image]

You are right, 1.8 GB of free RAM and my server, for some strange reason, is swapping. So I executed `top` -> F -> added the SWAP field. This is what I get:

[image]

Yep, apache is the only thing swapping. So I checked my `httpd.conf` and I changed the defaults to the below which helps a little bit to reduce swap usage:

```
KeepAlive Off

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20

ServerLimit       60
MaxRequestWorkers 60

MaxConnectionsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>
```

With the configuration above, everything should work fine in a webserver that is running with LOTS of free memory.

It's a very easy "bug" to reproduce and I think many people should be facing it... not only me... so why on all the forums I searched nobody posted something like this, yet?

Yes, sure, there are PLENTY of tutorials telling you how to tune apache, how other things on the server may be causing this swap... yeah, sad... but this case above is very clear, nothing fancy and probably a bunch of good folks around are spinning with this and have no idea what is causing their server to swap.

A good side note is that this server is not "idle" while reproducing this bug, I made it receive a few hundred requests per minute so I could check this bug. It's important to say that these requests were always very "light", the server was always with 1.8 GB of free RAM.

Comment: Who installed your CentOS system? What other changes were made to it?

Comment: Linode, they said nothing was changed, it's the minimal installation of Centos 7

Comment: Are you using any custom apache modules?  any custom packages, such as php that wasn't from the default repo?

Comment: no, only default apache installation.

Comment: Simulate the same system with Ubuntu right now and worked fine, really fine. Centos is a piece of shit, I always thought of it and now it's true.